# Weblogic 12.2.1 + Java 8 + Spring Data JPA + Hibernate 5.x Deployment conflict

Tags: java-8, weblogic, spring-data-jpa, weblogic12c, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to deploy an EAR file using WebLogic 12.2.1 with Hibernate 5.x and Spring-data-jpa 1.9.4. The same configuration deployed fine on Weblogic 12.1.3. JPA 2.1 is used on both of them.

Weblogic is throwing a `ClassNotFoundException` and looking for the QueryDsl library which is optional with spring-data:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysema.query.types.path.PathBuilder
```

The manifest for Spring-data even references this jar as optional. Since Oracle publishes none of their source I can't exactly debug the problem .. it seems to throw an error long before my `ApplicationContext` actually initializes any of the Spring wiring.

The same configuration deploys fine on Websphere 8.5.5. There seems to be some kind of deployment conflict with using Weblogic 12.2.1 but I can't spot any other meaningful differences. Is anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: I have the same problem with Weblogic 12.2.1. Did you manage to resolve this somehow?

Answer (score 10):

I managed to overcome this error by explicitly adding `querydsl-core` and `querydsl-jpa` to my poms.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```